# Retrieve any data which has only value

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

Hi,

I got this result using this query.

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id
FROM employees e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                FROM employees
                WHERE manager_id = e.employee_id)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Now, I want to retrieve any data only that has a unique value of department_id.

I mean, Steven, Neenda, and Nex are in department 90. So I don't want it.

However Alexander has department 60, and no one has department 60. So I want to retrieve it.

How could I get those data using query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option: use your current query as a CTE which is then re-used to

- return desired data
- find department that has only one employee (returned by your query)

---

```
WITH
   temp   
   AS
   -- this is your current query
      (SELECT employee_id,
              first_name,
              last_name,
              department_id
         FROM employees e
        WHERE EXISTS
                 (SELECT 'x'
                    FROM employees
                   WHERE manager_id = e.employee_id))
SELECT *
  FROM temp
 WHERE department_id IN (  SELECT department_id
                             FROM temp
                         GROUP BY department_id
                           HAVING COUNT (*) = 1);
```

Comment: Omg. Thanks Littlefoot. I coudn't even think of using WITH clause.
That helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to find "the employees who are managers where there is only a single manager in that department".

You can use the `COUNT` analytic function so that you do not have to query the same data twice:

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       department_id
FROM   (
  SELECT employee_id,
         first_name,
         last_name,
         department_id,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) AS num_managers_per_dept
  FROM   employees e
  WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE manager_id = e.employee_id)
)
WHERE  num_managers_per_dept = 1
ORDER BY employee_id;
```

Which, for the [`human_resources` schema](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest), outputs:

> | EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DEPARTMENT_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 103 | Alexander | Hunold | 60 |
> | 108 | Nancy | Greenberg | 100 |
> | 114 | Den | Raphaely | 30 |
> | 201 | Michael | Hartstein | 20 |
> | 205 | Shelley | Higgins | 110 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c88f0cc3f2b278f2f1b0ac3b35dbe0f3)*